# ¿Cómo determinar el valor de las filas en función de otra?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla con los siguientes campos:

```
RORD: Orden
Fecha: Fecha
HPUNTAJ: Puntaje
HDESCOL: Color de celda
HDESCAB: NOMBRE DE CABECERA
```

Quisiera saber cómo puedo generar una columna con las filas de mí tabla en función a los valores de otras filas.

Por ejemplo, todo con las filas con la misma fecha:

- Si la fila con **HDESCAB='Puntos Base'** y **HPUNTAJ=0**, la columna resultante solo debe tener los puntajes de las filas **'#AEF07B'** y **'#F0997B'**. Para el resto de las filas el resultado debe ser 0.
- Si la fila **HDESCAB='Puntos Base'** y **HPUNTAJ>0** la columna resultante debe tener los puntajes de todas las filas.

Aquí pueden ver la tabla original, a la izquierda, de color verde y amarillo las filas con la misma fecha. A la derecha, en la columna de color rojo (Dato Requerido):

[image: Muestra de tablas y resultado esperado]

Lo he intentado de muchas maneras pero no lo consigo.

Este es el código y el resultado que estoy obteniendo ahora:

```
SELECT RORD,Fecha,HDESCAB,HPUNTAJ,HCOLNAME,HDESCOL,
CASE when HPUNTAJ>0 AND HCOLNAME='HBPTOBAS' then 1 
     WHEN HPUNTAJ=0 AND HCOLNAME='HBPTOBAS' THEN 0 
     when  HDESCOL in('#AEF07B','#F0997B') then HPUNTAJ  
     when HPUNTAJ>0 AND HCOLNAME='HBPTOBAS' then HPUNTAJ else 0 
     end
FROM #Result   ORDER BY Fecha,1 ASC

RORD    Fecha   HPUNTAJ HDESCOL HDESCAB
1   2022-09-30  0   #BCC0AF Puntos Base
2   2022-09-30  0   #7BF0DC Saldo Cartera
3   2022-09-30  0   #7BF0DC Stock Clientes
4   2022-09-30  0   #7BF0DC -30 A 0
5   2022-09-30  0   #7BF0DC 1 A 30
6   2022-09-30  6   #7BF0DC Supervisión
7   2022-09-30  5   #7BF0DC Asesores Comis.
8   2022-09-30  0   #AEF07B Forma Extra
9   2022-09-30  2   #AEF07B Digital
10  2022-09-30  0   #AEF07B Captaciones
11  2022-09-30  2.5 #AEF07B Desempeño
12  2022-09-30  0   #AEF07B Riesgo Ope
13  2022-09-30  0   #F0997B Amonestaciones
1   2022-10-31  5   #BCC0AF Puntos Base
2   2022-10-31  2   #7BF0DC Saldo Cartera
3   2022-10-31  0   #7BF0DC Stock Clientes
4   2022-10-31  2   #7BF0DC -30 A 0
5   2022-10-31  0   #7BF0DC 1 A 30
6   2022-10-31  13  #7BF0DC Supervisión
7   2022-10-31  11  #7BF0DC Asesores Comis.
8   2022-10-31  0   #AEF07B Forma Extra
9   2022-10-31  2   #AEF07B Digital
10  2022-10-31  0   #AEF07B Captaciones
11  2022-10-31  2.5 #AEF07B Desempeño
12  2022-10-31  4   #AEF07B Riesgo Ope
13  2022-10-31  0   #F0997B Amonestaciones
```

Este es el código con el que creo la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[prueba](
    [RORD] [int] NULL,
    [Fecha] [date] NOT NULL,
    [HPUNTAJ] [float] NULL,
    [HDESCOL] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [HDESCAB] [varchar](250) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (13, CAST(N'2022-10-31' AS Date), 0, N'#F0997B', N'Amonestaciones')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (13, CAST(N'2022-09-30' AS Date), 0, N'#F0997B', N'Amonestaciones')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (7, CAST(N'2022-09-30' AS Date), 5, N'#7BF0DC', N'Asesores Comis.')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (7, CAST(N'2022-10-31' AS Date), 11, N'#7BF0DC', N'Asesores Comis.')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (10, CAST(N'2022-09-30' AS Date), 0, N'#AEF07B', N'Captaciones')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (10, CAST(N'2022-10-31' AS Date), 0, N'#AEF07B', N'Captaciones')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (11, CAST(N'2022-10-31' AS Date), 2.5, N'#AEF07B', N'Desempeño')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (11, CAST(N'2022-09-30' AS Date), 2.5, N'#AEF07B', N'Desempeño')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (9, CAST(N'2022-10-31' AS Date), 2, N'#AEF07B', N'Digital')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (9, CAST(N'2022-09-30' AS Date), 2, N'#AEF07B', N'Digital')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (5, CAST(N'2022-09-30' AS Date), 0, N'#7BF0DC', N'1 A 30')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (5, CAST(N'2022-10-31' AS Date), 0, N'#7BF0DC', N'1 A 30')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2022-10-31' AS Date), 2, N'#7BF0DC', N'-30 A 0')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2022-09-30' AS Date), 0, N'#7BF0DC', N'-30 A 0')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (8, CAST(N'2022-09-30' AS Date), 0, N'#AEF07B', N'Forma Extra')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (8, CAST(N'2022-10-31' AS Date), 0, N'#AEF07B', N'Forma Extra')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2022-10-31' AS Date), 5, N'#BCC0AF', N'Puntos Base')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2022-09-30' AS Date), 0, N'#BCC0AF', N'Puntos Base')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (12, CAST(N'2022-09-30' AS Date), 0, N'#AEF07B', N'Riesgo Ope')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (12, CAST(N'2022-10-31' AS Date), 4, N'#AEF07B', N'Riesgo Ope')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2022-10-31' AS Date), 2, N'#7BF0DC', N'Saldo Cartera')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2022-09-30' AS Date), 0, N'#7BF0DC', N'Saldo Cartera')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2022-09-30' AS Date), 0, N'#7BF0DC', N'Stock Clientes')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2022-10-31' AS Date), 0, N'#7BF0DC', N'Stock Clientes')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (6, CAST(N'2022-10-31' AS Date), 13, N'#7BF0DC', N'Supervisión')
INSERT [dbo].[prueba] ([RORD], [Fecha], [HPUNTAJ], [HDESCOL], [HDESCAB]) VALUES (6, CAST(N'2022-09-30' AS Date), 6, N'#7BF0DC', N'Supervisión')
```

Comment: Presta atención a como la redacté para que más personas lo puedan entender (espero no ser el único que no entendía). Asi mejoras las explicaciones de tus próximas preguntas.

Comment: @Mateo te lo agradezco y lo realizare en los próximas preguntas, te agradezco mucho tu ayuda 

Saludos desde Perú

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema con tus soluciones es que necesitas comparar con una fila distinta a la que hay que cambiarle el valor. Por lo tanto, necesitas hacer una segunda lectura a la tabla para verificar el valor de 'Puntos Base' para una fecha dada.

```
SELECT [RORD], 
        [Fecha], 
        [HPUNTAJ], 
        [HDESCOL], 
        [HDESCAB],
        CASE WHEN HDESCOL IN( '#AEF07B','#F0997B' ) -- Con estos colores siempre mantiene el valor
                  --Revisar si Puntos Base tiene un valor mayor a cero para esa fecha.
              OR EXISTS( SELECT * FROM prueba i
                          WHERE i.[HDESCAB] = 'Puntos Base' 
                          AND   i.[HPUNTAJ] > 0
                          AND   i.Fecha = p.Fecha) THEN HPUNTAJ ELSE 0 END
FROM prueba p
ORDER BY Fecha, RORD;
```

Comment: Cazare, Muchas gracias por responder, he revisao la query me mandaste pero no me da lo mismo que la foto enviada,
es decir si el puntaje base de una fecha es 0 solo debe pertenecer los valores de la columna HDESCOL IN( '#AEF07B','#F0997B' ) pero si la fecha valor >0 deben estar todos sus valores como estabán.

Comment: Perdón, hice un cambio de último momento para dejar las condiciones "positivas" y no cambié el AND por OR. Ya lo edité para que funcione como debería.

Answer (score 1):

El primer problema es detectar la condición de cambio, que según entendí es por fecha:

```
SELECT Fecha,
       MAX(CASE WHEN HDESCAB='Puntos Base'  AND HPUNTAJ=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Flag
       FROM Prueba
       GROUP BY Fecha
```

Dada esta primer condición hay que aplicarla a toda la fecha:

```
SELECT P.*,
       CASE WHEN F.Flag = 1 AND P.HDESCOL NOT IN ('#AEF07B','#F0997B') 
            THEN 0 
            ELSE HPUNTAJ 
       END as NEW_HPUNTAJ
       FROM Prueba P
       INNER JOIN (
            SELECT Fecha,
                   MAX(CASE WHEN HDESCAB='Puntos Base'  AND HPUNTAJ=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Flag
                   FROM Prueba
                   GROUP BY Fecha
       ) F
       ON P.Fecha = F.Fecha
       ORDER BY P.Fecha, P.RORD
```

Comment: Esta consulta tiene unos operadores costosos. Sería más eficiente si pasas las condiciones del `CASE` al `WHERE` y dejas de necesitar la agrupación de datos por completo.